# Not able to access the $.getJSON function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

Here is a code which try to access the $.getJSON, but it doesn't responding. What may be the possible reason for this.

```
        function getTerms()
        {
            alert("hello"); //it alerts hello           
            $.getJSON('http://localhost/context-search.php?callback=?', function(r) {
                //not here
                alert("Hello");
            });
        }
        $(document).ready(function(){
        alert("hello");         
        getTerms(); 
    });
```

context-search.php returns json data in the form of

**{"options":["osi","tcp","ip","http protcol","ethernet","network protocol","protocol meaning\n"]}**

Where have I possibly gone wrong?? Please help me through this! 
Thank You!! :)

Comment: @Joseph console outputs nothing.. it's blank!!

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your console log?
If it doesn't contain an error, do a json request like this instead

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data,
    success: function(){},
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("error " + textStatus);
        console.log("incoming Text " + jqXHR.responseText);
    }
});
```

Which will give you proper error handling.

Comment: on using ur function it says data is not defined!! What's this?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Assuming this is running on localhost have you tried

$.getJSON('/context-search.php?callback=?', ...);

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON('/ITTA/SavePreference/?t=' + new Date(), { id: id3 },
                   function (data) {
                       if (data != null && data != undefined && data != '') {
                           top.location.href = '/ITTA/Entries/' + id3;
                       }
                   }); });
```